# Some case-specific questions about multi-threading

Tags: java

**Question 1.**
If we consider the following class:

```
public class Test {
    public static LinkedList<String> list;
}
```

How would you make getting/setting thread-safe for the variable 'list'?

I guess I could do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    private static LinkedList<String> list;

    public static synchronized LinkedList<String> getList() {
        return new LinkedList<>(list);
    }

    public static synchronized void setList(LinkedList<String> data) {
        list = new LinkedList<>(data);
    }
}
```

**Question 2.**

But how thread-safe is this? Would I have to initialize a new list each time to ensure other copies don't affect the variable?

**Question 3.**

If we consider this instead:

```
public class Test {
    private static LinkedList<String> list;

    public static synchronized void ManipulateList() {
        // do stuff to 'list'
    }

    public static synchronized void ChangeList() {
        // do more stuff to 'list'
    }
}
```

where both methods 'ManipulateList' and 'ChangeList' might add or remove variables to the same list

Is this thread-safe? Does this mean that if thread 1 is accessing 'ManipulateList' then thread 2 is not able to access 'ChangeList' until thread 1 finishes accessing 'ManipulateList'?

I'm just not sure if I'm understanding the effects correctly.

Comment: Why would `getList` return a new `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1.**

```
public static LinkedList<String> list;
```

> How would you make getting/setting thread-safe for the variable
>   'list'?

Avoid global [mutable] state. Just get rid of it.

**Question 2.**

```
public class Test {
    private static LinkedList<String> list;

    public static synchronized LinkedList<String> getList() {
        return new LinkedList<>(list);
    }

    public static synchronized void setList(LinkedList<String> data) {
        list = new LinkedList<>(data);
    }
}
```

> But how thread-safe is this? Would I have to initialize a new list
>   each time to ensure other copies don't affect the variable?

(I am going to assume by *this* you mean `Test.list` not the passed in  `data` which, due to the defects of the Java collection library, is mutable itself.

So you are always accessing the list with the same lock held. You are always copying the list when dealing with the outside world. The members of the list are immutable, so you don't need any deep copying. All good.

The method have the lock held over an expensive operation not involving the variable, so we should do better here.

```
public static synchronized LinkedList<String> getList() {
    // The `LinkedList` list points to is never mutated after set.
    LinkedList<String> local;
    synchronized (Test.class) {
        local = list;
    }
    return new LinkedList<>(local);
}

public static void setList(LinkedList<String> data) {
    LinkedList<String> local = new LinkedList<>(data);
    synchronized (Test.class) {
        list = local;
    }
}
```

In theory, even without the change the lock needn't be held continuously for the entire copy. As it is a public lock object (but naughty, but common) `data` could `wait` on it releasing the lock temporarily. Obviously not significant here, but in real world cases it may lead to strangeness.

Slightly more obscurely, `list` could be made `volatile` and the lock elided.

**Question 3.**

```
    private static LinkedList<String> list;

    public static synchronized void ManipulateList() {
        // do stuff to 'list'
    }

    public static synchronized void ChangeList() {
        // do more stuff to 'list'
    }
```

> Is this thread-safe? Does this mean that if thread 1 is accessing
>   'ManipulateList' then thread 2 is not able to access 'ChangeList'
>   until thread 1 finishes accessing 'ManipulateList'?

Yes. Other than there may be `wait`s and one of the methods could call the other, perhaps indirectly.

**General notes.**

- Remove global [mutable] state.
- Try to avoid shared mutable object (keep shared object immutable and mutable objects unshared).
- Reduce the amount of code and time that locks are held for.
- Copy mutable inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

> I guess I could do something like this:

This isn't thread safe.

Specifically, the setter:

```
public static synchronized void setList(LinkedList<String> data) {
    list = new LinkedList<>(data);
}
```

does not enforce that `data` is accessed exclusively for the duration of the `setList` method. As such, other threads could modify the list during the implicit iteration.

---

The code in question 3 is fine with respect to updates to the list, because the fact the methods are synchronized means that the list is accessed mutually exclusively, and the effects of one method invocation are visible to subsequent invocations.

But it's not entirely safe, because nefarious code can acquire (and hold onto) the monitor of `Test`, which could lead to a deadlock.

You can fix this specific issue by having an explicit monitor that can only be acquired inside the class:

```
class Test {
  private final Object obj = new Object();

  public static void ManipulateList() {
    synchronized (obj) { ... }
  }

  public static void ChangeList() {
    synchronized (obj) { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also if thats not thread safe, then how would you make it thread safe?

Comment: That's fine with respect to updates to the list, because the fact the methods are synchronized means that the list is accessed mutually exclusively, and the effects of one method invocation are visible to subsequent invocations. But it's not entirely safe, because nefarious code can acquire (and hold onto) the monitor of `Test`, which could lead to a deadlock.

Comment: Therefore, how would you deal with this situation and create something that is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that subclasses your Test class could break your synchronization scheme because subclasses could directly access the list without the method-synchronization - either by *subclassing* your Test class or through *reflection*.

```
public class MyTestClass extends Test {

    // blah...

    public static changeTheList() {

        this.list.add("Bypasses synchronization through direct access to the list.");

    }

}
```

A better solution for synchronization is to initialize your list with a synchronized wrapper, like this:

```
public class Test {

    private static LinkedList<String> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<>());

    public static synchronized LinkedList<String> getList() {

        return list;

    }

    public static synchronized void setList(LinkedList<String> newList) {

        list = newList;

    }

}
```

In the second snippet, you can now safely sub-class your Test class and access the list in a thread-safe manner because the *list* ***itself*** is synchronized.

You other option is to mark your Test class as final but you would still need to fix your implementation (you re-initialize the list in your getter's & setter's which is not a good idea).

Also -- I might suggest you look at some tutorials regarding synchronization -- a couple of suggestions:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-synchronized-collections

https://howtodoinjava.com/java/collections/arraylist/synchronize-arraylist/

Comment: The first code example has `list` `public` and later it's `private`, so subclassing is irrelevant. With respect to reflection, if you're using that (with `setAccessible` permitted) all bets are off for everything. If you directly store or return the list, it may (will) be mutated outside of the locks.